# Are DTO's necessary when sending JSON from a RESTful web service?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I'm attempting to build a RESTful web service using Spring MVC. I'm using Jackson's fasterxml JSON parser for communication between the client and server side.

I'm trying to determine whether or not to implement DTO's (Data Transfer Objects) into my RESTful API. I'm currently utilizing Jackson's `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)` and `@JsonIgnore` annotations to prevent sensitive fields (such as passwords) from being sent to the client side.

So, are DTO's necessary when using JSON for communication between the client and the server when omitting sensitive fields from the response body or are the annotations `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty` sufficient enough to prevent sensitive data leakage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you talk about serializing entities to json instead of using DTOs which is not very clear, yes DTOs would be the proper choice from an architectural point of view. Underneath controllers there most commonly is the service layer which functions on some domain, let's say persistence entities or entities coming from a queuing system.

It is sane to isolate your REST API from your domain and map lower level domain entities to DTOs at service level, most commonly using a POJO mapper.

This would have some performance impact which you can optimize but has the benefit of structural isolation between layers.

The second benefit is that you can aggregate information from lower layers and manipulate your REST interface as serves you best,

If again we talk about entities it's wrong to add REST api attributes in persistence layer.

All this from a conceptual point of view. 
Another thing that should prevent you from serving entities of JPA2 is that the objects returned from queries are enhanced objects so using a mapper will again give you more control.

Choosing the mapper configuration is a bit tricky though since if you expose crud operations as in the persistence/domain level mapping becomes redundant.
Exposing entities will only cause scaling problems

Comment: What's the purpose of using the DTO's given the fact that I'm utilizing Jackson's `@JsonIgnore`? For instance, let's say I have a `User` object with `id`, `username` and `password`. I add `@JsonIgnore` to the password field so that way when a user logs on, I only return `id` and `username` as the `password` field is ignored when the object is serialized. Are there any security vulnerabilities with this approach? Do I need a DTO in that given example?

Comment: This will work, but architecturally it's not preferred. 

Later on you will need create complex APIs which, if stuck to exposing entities you will mix entities and transient DTOs and your code-base will be polluted.

Comment: So essentially, for each new request for information, I need a DTO which contains a subset of fields identical to fields within the mapped entity? For instance, if I create a form for signing up, I'd need a UserDTO which contains the fields from the form with simple getters and setters, no more, no less?

Comment: @JakeMiller What happens if you want to refactor your JPA entities without breaking your Web API?